how to make dynamic choicefields based on models in django forms?
I have a Group Model that I want to use it's objects in my form. I would like to have a dynamic choices tuple based on Group model objects! How can I do this?
I used the code below :
class Employee_Form(forms.Form):
GROUPS = ()
try:
    GROUPS = (
    )
    for i in Group.objects.all():
        GROUPS += ((i.name , i.name),)
except:
    pass
phone = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
position = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
group = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GROUPS)

This code have a problem . every time you add a new object to your model you have to restart the server after that But it does not recommended!
and one important thing is I want to use forms.Form not the modelForm.

Use a ModelChoiceField, don't use name as identifier.

What you are trying to do, already exists: a ModelChoiceField form field [Django-doc], this takes a QuerySet, and uses the primary key as identifier to determined the picked item:
class Employee_Form(forms.Form):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=12)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    position = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    group = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all())

Thank you But I have a question ! When I used that kind of code that i wrote , I had errors when migrating beacuse I wanted to import that table that not exists . if I use this ModelChoiceField , I will get that error again or no?

Typically your models.py should not import forms.py, so the cyclic dependency should be removed.

@Alirezajavanpour querysets are lazy (don't make a query until necessary), you got an error with your solution because you looped over the queryset, thereby causing it to run an actual DB query. Another problem with your solution would have been that even if you got the migration to run your form would serve stale choices to the users.
